# CSS Table-cell spacing

Tags: css, css-tables

I've got a few images that are being displayed using `display: table-cell;`

But they are all shoved over to the left...how would I create some space in between them?

Here is the section where it is located:

```
.ProductList li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    min-height: 250px;
    width: 250px !important;
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-right: -1px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What HTML are you using? Are the `img` tags in the `li`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an easy fix, you could add some right padding.

It might also be a good idea to take a look at bootstrap, a front-end framework. Perfect for such things.